# Plotting a color histogram in python

Tags: python, image, histogram

I have a jpeg image and want to plot a histogram of how frequently each color occurs in the image. I am able to generate a frequency table using pymorph.histogram(), but I don't know the actual color that each of the 256 colors indices correspond to. How can I generate this palette?
Further, is there an way to just generate a histogram plot of all these numbers, with the colors indicated (not a number in the range 0-255, but the actual color displayed)?

My frequency list is generated using this code:

```
import pymorph
import Image

im=Image.open('image.jpg')
im=np.asarray(im)
hist_im=pymorph.histogram(im)
```

Comment: Note that from the documentation pymorph only handles grayscale or binary images. So each of the 256 values is simply a level of gray.

Comment: Take a look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182891/plot-image-color-histogram-using-matplotlib

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how 3 colors could be represented accurately in 256 values. I assumed there was a standard set of 256 colors which the image was reduced to.