# Analysis of images using PIL in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I found this code:

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

im = Image.open('./color_gradient.png')  
w, h = im.size  
colors = im.getcolors(w*h)

def hexencode(rgb):
 r=rgb[0]
 g=rgb[1]
 b=rgb[2]
 return '#%02x%02x%02x' % (r,g,b)

for idx, c in enumerate(colors):
    plt.bar(idx, c[0], color=hexencode(c[1]),edgecolor=hexencode(c[1]))
plot.show()
```

For the exact link one can look here-[Plot image color histogram using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182891/plot-image-color-histogram-using-matplotlib)

My questions are what are the meaning of the axes, and how can I generate a table out these values? I would like to run some statistics, like percent of green, or red in the picture...

Thanks

Comment: The only reason you are getting away with this title is that you've misspelt the word Question. What is your real question?

Comment: (for the record I changed the title)

Answer (score 1):

From the [PIL Documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm):

> **getcolors**
>
> im.getcolors() => a list of (count, color) tuples or None
>
> im.getcolors(maxcolors) => a list of (count, color) tuples or None

The Y axis in the referred graph is the pixel count of that colour and the X axis comprises the (unsorted?) list of colours in the graph.

Comment: Trying to use im.getcolors(), returns None

Comment: That should go in your question